# Nosuchelementfound exception in Selenium Webdriver

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

As a new learner for Selenium, I am trying to identify a basic element on the Google page for the Google Search button. However I am getting a `NoSuchElementException` even though the element is perfectly visible on the page.

Code Snippet :

```
String driverPath = "C:\\Users\\nchaudhary006\\IEDriverServer.exe";
System.setProperty("webdriver.ie.driver",driverPath);
DesiredCapabilities capabilities = DesiredCapabilities.internetExplorer();
        capabilities.setCapability(InternetExplorerDriver.INTRODUCE_FLAKINESS_BY_IGNORING_SECURITY_DOMAINS, true);
InternetExplorerDriver  driver = new InternetExplorerDriver(capabilities);

driver.manage().window().maximize();
driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(60, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
driver.get("https://google.com");
driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(60, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

driver.findElement(By.name("btnK"));
```

Solutions Tried :

1. Element until visible option
2. Scroll down so that page is in view
3. Identifying element by xpath, id , name, etc.
4. All possible wait combinations.

What can I be possibly doing wrong?

Comment: Which element are you referring by `name` as `btnK` ?

Comment: try as `new WebDriverWait(driver, 60).until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.name("btnK")))`

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure to which element you exactly referred by `name` as `btnK` but on `https://google.com` there is a Search field by `name` as `q`

Using Selenium 3.4.0, IEDriverServer 3.4.0 & IE 10.x (& above) the below code will put "Neha Chaudhary" in the Search field.

A few words about the Solution:

1. Once you set ImplicitlyWait at the begining, it remains valid throughout your execution. So you don't have to mention again & again.
2. Instead of `InternetExplorerDriver` implementation you must use the `WebDriver` interface.
3. While you search for an element `driver.findElement(By.name("btnK"));` either store it as a `WebElement` for future use or perform some action by `click()` or `sendKeys("Neha Chaudhary")`
4. Here is the working code snippet:

   ```
   String driverPath = "C:\\Utility\\BrowserDrivers\\IEDriverServer.exe";
   System.setProperty("webdriver.ie.driver",driverPath);
   DesiredCapabilities capabilities = DesiredCapabilities.internetExplorer();
   capabilities.setCapability(InternetExplorerDriver.INTRODUCE_FLAKINESS_BY_IGNORING_SECURITY_DOMAINS, true);
   WebDriver  driver = new InternetExplorerDriver(capabilities);
   driver.manage().window().maximize();
   driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
   driver.get("https://google.com");
   driver.findElement(By.name("q")).sendKeys("Neha Chaudhary");
   ```

Let me know if this Answers your Question.